# Can't boot into ubuntu server 16.04 after successful installation

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, grub

I've installed 16.04 on Dell R710 server on RAID6.
Boot mode is set to UEFI in BIOS.

After successful installation it stays in `grub>` console.

Output to `ls` command is

```
(hd0) (hd1) (hd1,apple2) (hd1,apple1) (hd1,msdos2)  (cd0)
```

- `hd0` is my RAID6 disk
- `hd1` is the USB stick which I install Ubuntu 16.04 from

Using the rescure option in USB stick I've accessed a `/bin/sh` terminal and checked with `fdisk -l` to make sure it contains `grub.cfg` and its content is as expected

```
search.fs_uuid b53fe0e6-485e-4278-a604-d309960bc542 root hd0,gpt2
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

In `grub>` console I tried typing first line of above and it says

```
error: failure reading sector 0x0 from 'cd0'
error: failure reading sector 0x0 from 'cd0'.
error: no such device: b53fe0e6-485e-4278-a604-d309960bc542
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue in Ubuntu 18.04. Dell R710, raid6, same size. Hoping to find a way to use the whole raid. Haven't attempted splitting it into smaller raid sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My RAID6 ends up 3.6TB.
I've made a RAID1 drive with 600GB. Then it installs fine.
Not sure its the BIOS or GRUB issue.
Hope it helps someone with same issue.